# Can't open file on remote 2012 server with SMB2 enabled

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, server-message-block

I have two 2012 R2 servers.  The one acting as the file server has SMB2/3 enabled.  The one acting as the client can open files on the server if SMB2 is disabled.  If I enable SMB2 though when I try to open the file the System process on the client machine starts to use a high amount of CPU and the file never opens.

Process Explorer screen cap:
[System process Interrupts using CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZF6Z.png)

SMB server configuration:

```
C:\Users\ARAXI>powershell Get-SmbServerConfiguration

AnnounceServer                  : False
AsynchronousCredits             : 64
AutoShareServer                 : True
AutoShareWorkstation            : True
CachedOpenLimit                 : 5
AnnounceComment                 :
EnableDownlevelTimewarp         : False
EnableLeasing                   : True
EnableMultiChannel              : True
EnableStrictNameChecking        : True
AutoDisconnectTimeout           : 0
DurableHandleV2TimeoutInSeconds : 30
EnableAuthenticateUserSharing   : False
EnableForcedLogoff              : True
EnableOplocks                   : True
EnableSecuritySignature         : False
ServerHidden                    : True
IrpStackSize                    : 15
KeepAliveTime                   : 2
MaxChannelPerSession            : 32
MaxMpxCount                     : 50
MaxSessionPerConnection         : 16384
MaxThreadsPerQueue              : 20
MaxWorkItems                    : 1
NullSessionPipes                :
NullSessionShares               :
OplockBreakWait                 : 35
PendingClientTimeoutInSeconds   : 120
RequireSecuritySignature        : False
EnableSMB1Protocol              : True
EnableSMB2Protocol              : True
Smb2CreditsMax                  : 16384
Smb2CreditsMin                  : 768
SmbServerNameHardeningLevel     : 0
TreatHostAsStableStorage        : False
ValidateAliasNotCircular        : True
ValidateShareScope              : True
ValidateShareScopeNotAliased    : True
ValidateTargetName              : True
EncryptData                     : False
RejectUnencryptedAccess         : True
```

SMB client configuration:

```
C:\>powershell Get-SmbClientConfiguration

ConnectionCountPerRssNetworkInterface : 4
DirectoryCacheEntriesMax              : 16
DirectoryCacheEntrySizeMax            : 65536
DirectoryCacheLifetime                : 10
EnableBandwidthThrottling             : True
EnableByteRangeLockingOnReadOnlyFiles : True
EnableLargeMtu                        : True
EnableMultiChannel                    : True
DormantFileLimit                      : 1023
EnableSecuritySignature               : True
ExtendedSessionTimeout                : 1000
FileInfoCacheEntriesMax               : 64
FileInfoCacheLifetime                 : 10
FileNotFoundCacheEntriesMax           : 128
FileNotFoundCacheLifetime             : 5
KeepConn                              : 600
MaxCmds                               : 2048
MaximumConnectionCountPerServer       : 32
OplocksDisabled                       : False
RequireSecuritySignature              : False
SessionTimeout                        : 60
UseOpportunisticLocking               : True
WindowSizeThreshold                   : 1
```

I have run WPR while trying to open the file - the ETL file is here:
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw6tb4tS9dQyeWEwUUp1NDYyZjQ/view?usp=sharing